# Add value to table column by looking up in score table

Tags: r, lookup

I have one table with an average cost "costmel"
and I have one table with a risk score 1-6 between the high-low ranges of those average costs.

```
aggProb_avCostMeld table:

          costmel
1         19.39
2         0.00
3         4889.71
4         4612.82
5         0.00
6         3812.52

RisicoKostSchaal table:

  Schaal low     high
1      1   0 1.75e+02
2      2 175 3.50e+02
3      3 350 5.25e+02
4      4 525 7.00e+02
5      5 700 8.75e+02
6      6 875 1.00e+08
```

What I want to do is for each i in aggProb_avCostMeld$costmel,
check if it falls within y of RisicoKostSchaal high low range and return the corresponding number of RisicoKostSchaal$Schaal and put that in a new column "costrisk" in the aggProb_avCostMeld table.

The code that I tried is:

```
for(i in aggProb_avCostMeld$costmel) {
  for (y in RisicoKostSchaal ){
    if(aggProb_avCostMeld$costmel[i] >= RisicoKostSchaal$low[y] & aggProb_avCostMeld$costmel[i] < RisicoKostSchaal$high[y]){
  aggProb_avCostMeld$costrisk[i] <- RisicoKostSchaal$Schaal[y]
    }

  }
}
```

But that didn't work.

```
dput(aggProb_avCostMeld)
c(19.3984518231819, 0, 4889.71644908616, 4612.82921161826, 0, 
3812.52550091075, 0, 0, 0, 1484.24951267057, 0, 789.423206278027, 
2529.65298303229, 3600.89832689833)

dput(RisicoKostSchaal)
structure(list(Schaal = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), low = c(0, 175, 
350, 525, 700, 875), high = c(175, 350, 525, 700, 875, 1e+08)), .Names = c("Schaal", 
"low", "high"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please add the result of `dput(aggProb_avCostMeld)` and `dput(RisicoKostSchaal)` to your question, it will be easier to copy/paste.

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: something like `RisicoKostSchaal$Schaal[sapply(aggProb_avCostMeld$costmel, function(i) which(i >= RisicoKostSchaal$low & i <= RisicoKostSchaal$high))]`

Comment: I've added the dput results of both tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can :

**1st**. Define a function to get `Schaal` of `RisicoKostSchaal` when a specific number fall in range `c(low, high)`:

```
> checkInRange <- function(num) {
 RisicoKostSchaal$Schaal[which(RisicoKostSchaal$low <= num & RisicoKostSchaal$high >= num)]
 }
```

**2nd**. **Apply** this function to every element in `aggProb_avCostMeld`:

```
> aggProb_avCostMeld$costrisk  <- sapply(aggProb_avCostMeld$costmel, checkInRange)


> aggProb_avCostMeld
 #      costmel costrisk
 #1:   19.39845        1
 #2:    0.00000        1
 #3: 4889.71645        6
 #4: 4612.82921        6
 #5:    0.00000        1
 #6: 3812.52550        6
 #7:    0.00000        1
 #8:    0.00000        1
 #9:    0.00000        1
#10: 1484.24951        6
#11:    0.00000        1
#12:  789.42321        5
#13: 2529.65298        6
#14: 3600.89833        6
```

Comment: You can remove the `return` in your function, a R function will always return the value of its last statement, hence a `return` call just add for the interpreter the overhead of searching the `return` function which is already called at end of the function. I agree this is more self explaining to read, but on large dataset, the overhead could be non negligible.